# How to set progress for the ProgressBar after using the Power button?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-widget, android-progressbar

Recently I came across an issue when I tried to set the progress for the ProgressBar after I pressed the Power button. I'm using the onSaveInstanceState method to save all information needed and then I restore the values in onCreate. To simplify the issue I am using hardcoded values when restoring the values.

When I initialise the values for the ProgressBar everything works as expected, however when I press the Power button and then press the Power button again to wake up the (app) Activity the ProgressBar shows 0 progress in the Android Studio Layout inspector. Interestingly the Android Studio Logcat shows the correct information.

**What I tried to do so far**:
I checked that I have a connection to the correct ProgressBar by setVisibility for the ProgressBar GONE and it is working.
I tried to invalidate the ProgressBar and other views without luck.

**My first question**: How to set and show the progress in ProgressBar correctly after the app wakes up?

**My Second question**: Why my solution does not work when I set the values as hardcoded?

```
onCreate

...
  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            restoreInstanceStateForProgressBar(savedInstanceState);
        } else {
            initProgressBarForEndSession( "Title", "Message",
                    "Progress Bar 1", FOURTH_PROGRESS_BAR_MAX, fourthProgressBarProgress,
                    "Progress Bar 2", FIFTH_PROGRESS_BAR_MAX, fifthProgressBarProgress
            );
        }

...



private void restoreInstanceStateForProgressBar(@NonNull Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        binding.includeProgressBarEndSession.clRoot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ConstraintLayout clRoot = (ConstraintLayout)   
        findViewById(R.id.includeProgressBarEndSession);
        if (clRoot != null) {
            int clRootChildrenCount = clRoot.getChildCount();
            View rootTitleView = clRoot.getChildAt(0);
            if (rootTitleView instanceof TextView) {
                TextView rootTitle = (TextView) 
                clRoot.getChildAt(0);
                rootTitle.setText("Title");
            }
            View rootMessageView = clRoot.getChildAt(1);
            if (rootMessageView instanceof TextView) {
                /*
                assign the value
                 */
                TextView rootMessage = ((TextView) 
                clRoot.getChildAt(1));
                rootMessage.setText("Message");
            }
        }


        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) 
        findViewById(R.id.clRootPb);
        if (constraintLayout != null) {
            int clChildrenCount = 
            constraintLayout.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < clChildrenCount; i++) {
                View incProgressBarView = 
                constraintLayout.getChildAt(i);
                if (incProgressBarView instanceof  
                ConstraintLayout) {
                    ConstraintLayout incProgressBar = 
                   (ConstraintLayout) 
                     constraintLayout.getChildAt(i);
                    if (i == 3 || i == 4) {
                        
                    incProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        View tvPbTitleView = 
                        incProgressBar.getChildAt(0);
                        if (tvPbTitleView instanceof TextView) 
                        {
                            TextView tvPbTitle = (TextView) 
                            incProgressBar.getChildAt(0);
                            tvPbTitle.setText("tvPbTitle");
                        }
                        View pbView = 
                        incProgressBar.getChildAt(1);
                        if (pbView instanceof ProgressBar) {
                            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) 
                            incProgressBar.getChildAt(1);

                            pb.setProgress(100);

                            System.out.println("\nTAG" +

          "\nrestoreInstanceStateForProgressBar" + "" +
          "\nProgressBar Visibility: " + pb.getVisibility() + "" +
           "\nProgressBar Max: " + pb.getMax() + "" +
           "\nProgressBar Progress: " + pb.getProgress());

                             /*
                               test set View.GONE for the  
                               ProgressBar
                             */

                            // pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                        View tvPbPercentageView = 
                        incProgressBar.getChildAt(2);
                        if (tvPbPercentageView instanceof 
                        TextView) {
                            TextView tvPbPercentage = 
                            (TextView)    

                            incProgressBar.getChildAt(2);
                            tvPbPercentage.setText("...%");

                        }
                        View tvPbDoneView = 
                        incProgressBar.getChildAt(3);
                        if (tvPbDoneView instanceof TextView) {
                            TextView tvPbDone = (TextView) 
                            incProgressBar.getChildAt(3);
                            tvPbDone.setText("...of...");

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

**Layout Inspector before Power button pressed:**

[image: Layout Inspector before Power button pressed]

**Layout Inspector after wake up:**
[image: Layout Inspector after wake up]

**Logcat after wake up:**

[image: Logcat after wake up]